# using raw_input in a while loop and assigning it to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
is42= False
while(raw_input()):
    d = _
    if d == 42:
      is42 = True
    if not is42:
      print d
```

for this python block of code I want to use outside of the interactive prompt mode. So I can't use _ as the last output. How do I assign raw_input to a variable? I'm doing an exercise off a site. about 5 values is the input and I'm suppose to spit some output out for each corresponding input value. What's the best way to take in this input to do that?

Comment: Always check the official doc first. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#raw_input

Comment: `d = raw_input("Choose a number: ")`

Comment: In addition to two comments above: if you are just starting python please, try to learn [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3) rather than python 2. Python 2 is a legacy now, it is being [recommended](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3/) to use the newest version if you can.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 I think python2.7 is still used by a lot of medical researchers

Comment: @A.Lau I am aware that python 2 is being used widley however this does not mean that it shouldn't be changed. This version however maintained, will not get any new features not improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be very inefficient logic.  Do you really need the **is42** status flag as well?  If not, you might want something like

```
stuff = raw_input()
while stuff:
    if stuff != "42":
         print stuff
    stuff = raw_input()
```

Does that fix enough of your troubles?

Answer (score 0):

```
is42=False
while(!is42):
    d = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    is42 = d==42
    print "d = ", d
```

That should do it if I understand the requirements of your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Python!

The `raw_input()` function returns the input read as a string. So where you have `d = _`, you can replace that with `d = raw_input()`. A question I have for you is why you had it inside the while condition? If you wanted it to keep asking the user for a number over and over, then replace `while(raw_input()):` with `while True:`.

One more thing, `raw_input()` always returns a string. So if you run `print '30' == 30`, you'll see that a string representation of 30 is not equal to the number representation of 30. But that's not a problem! You can turn the return value of `raw_input()` into an integer type by replacing `d = raw_input()` with `d = int(raw_input())`.

Now there will be another problem when the user gives you an input that can't be converted to an integer, but handling that can be an exercise for you. :)

Final code:

```
is42= False
while True:
    d = int(raw_input())
    if d == 42:
      is42 = True
    if not is42:
      print d
```